# SOAPUI, JsonSlurper returns null even if json data is proper

Tags: groovy, soapui

In SOAPUI, JsonSlurper is returning `null` even if json data is proper. The below `jsonObj` gives `null`. Is it because of lengthy data or some other thing. I verified my data format and its proper.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText( messageExchange.response.contentAsString )
```

Comment: Same problem :-(

Does SoapUI just use a mock?

I tried putting groovy-all.jar into the JRE's "lib/ext" but no joy.

Are you using Java 6?

Comment: Hi, I'm new to SoapUI and I'm surely missing something but I'm wondering why you don't parse context.Response, like jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(context.Response) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so no go. This may be due to running SoapUI on Java 6 (it won't work with Java 7) or not.

Therefore, workaround.

The examples found on the Internet are not necessarily helpful because:

- They may be written by people not necessarily fluent with Groovy
- The examples hide a fundamental problem: The objects one gets from SoapUI seem to behave differently in different contexts, e.g. in SOAP or REST contexts the actual classes of the objects is different, and although the same method calls can be performed, the returned values will differ (you get an XML string instead of a JSON string). As Groovy is weakly typed and encourages duck typing, the examples given may fail in unexpected and not immediately evident ways.
- The examples are missing logging and assertions.

These said, here we go. We want to obtain the value of "InquiryId" which can be found in the response, which we know is represented by a JSON string.

```
// Get projet associated to current "testRunner" by walking up the tree of objects    
// "testRunner" is probably a http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/support/AbstractTestCaseRunner.html    

def myProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project

// "myProject" is probably a http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProject.html 
// Let's verify this! If we have guessed wrongly, the script will fail

assert myProject instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject

// Get the appropriate TestStep by walking down the tree of objects
// It is recommended to use getXByName() throughout unless you want to 
// confuse yourself by using mixed accessor styles working only on some
// classes that may appear in this expression:

def myStep = myProject.getTestSuiteByName("Global test suite").getTestCaseByName("Test Case Foo").getTestStepByName("Create Inquiry")

// The result is probably a http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlTestStep.html
// Let's verify this! If we have guessed wrongly, the script will fail

assert myStep instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestStep

// Getting JSON string can be done like this. One can also do
// 'otherStep.getPropertyValue("reponse") as String' 

def jsonString = otherStep.testRequest.response.contentAsString

// Let's log what we got here:     

log.info "Returned JSON string is '${jsonString}'"

// What we cannot do with the 'jsonString' is:
// Give it to SoapUI's "XMLHolder" for parsing, because, in spite of people
// saying so, it does not seem to understand JSON.
// Give it to JsonSlurper because JsonSlurper returns null
// So we extract the value by scanning the String directly using a regular 
// expression. See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions
// The pattern say: Look for something that starts with 
// {"InquiryId":"
// and ends with
// "}
// and grab the characters between these endings.
// We then look for "anywhere in the passed String" for the above using "find()"
// rather than "match()" which would demand precise matching of the whole String.

def pattern = ~/\{"InquiryId":"(.+?)"\}/    
def matcher = pattern.matcher(jsonString)

if (matcher.find()) {    
   def inqId = matcher.group(1)    
   log.info "Returned string is '${inqId}'"
   // We are done here
   return inqId    
}    
else {    
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not extract InquiryId from '$jsonString'")    
}
```